# Property defined in parent not available in child pom

Tags: maven, maven-3

Structure of the two apps we develop

```
  -
  ----- app_one
          -
          --- pom.xml (aggregator pom to build all modules part of the app)
          -
          --- app_one_version_module
                -
                --- pom.xml (parent module defining the app version)
                -
          --- module_one
          --- module_two
 -
 ----- app_two
         -
         --- pom.xml (aggregator pom to build all modules part of the app)
         -
         --- app_two_version_module
               -
               --- pom.xml (parent module defining the app version)
               -
         --- module_three
         --- module_four
```

The parent pom and individual project poms looks like the following for project one.

```
parent pom.xml
--------------
<properties>
  <appone.version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</appone.version>
</properties>

module_one pom.xml
------------------
<parent>
  <version>${appone.version}</version>
  <relativePath>../.</relativePath>
</parent>

module_two pom.xml
------------------
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
       <artifactId>module_one</artifactId>
       <version>${appone.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<parent>
  <version>${appone.version}</version>
  <relativePath>../.</relativePath>
</parent>
```

App2 also is organized in similar manner.

Within individual apps, all modules have the same version. So, `module_one` and `module_two` will have same version and `module_three` and `module_four` will have same version as they're developed together.

**The problem arised when `module_three` has to depend on `module_two`.**  Let's say app_one is current at version `2.0-SNAPSHOT` and app_two is at version `3.1-SNAPSHOT`.

```
module_three pom.xml
--------------------
<properties>
  <otherapp.version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</otherapp.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
       <artifactId>module_two</artifactId>
       <version>${otherapp.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

When I try to build app_two maven identifies that it needs `module_two` at version `2.0-SNAPSHOT` to build `module_three`. But, it is not able to evaluate/interpolate the expression `<version>${appone.version}</version>` inside the pom.xml of `module_two`. So, the build is failing. As we can see in the snippet, the property `appone.version` is defined in parent pom of app_one and `module_two` has correct definition of parent tag.
If I try to build app_one by itself, it gets built successfully.

I'm not able to understand what went wrong here. Help is appreciated.

Comment: <appone.version>2.0-SNAPSHOT&</appone.version>
the "&" is not a valid character. 
Maybe you just made a typo when you created the post, or not?...

Comment: @aurelius : yes, that's a typo while writing the post. Correcting now. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: have you clean installed first app, after changing the version in appOne?
it seems that the version you use in the second app is not present on your local repository, under .m2 directory

Comment: @aurelius : yes I did. The problem is the expression `${appone.version}` in `pom.xml` of `module_two` is not being evaluated. The URL generated by maven has `${appone.version}` instead of it's value.